# Mathematics and the observer in Wolfram Fundamental Physics Project...?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, philosophy-of-mathematics, philosophy-of-physics, platonism

In this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TrnteM9E2tI&t=6633s) about mathematics in the Wolfram Physics Project, Stephen Wolfram says at minute 1:49:37 something that seems contradictory:

He begins by apparently saying that the human observer determines what is true in mathematics and denies that, as Hilbert said, you can have axioms of all types (you can have axioms that talk about chairs and tables just as you can have axioms about integers) and that it is not true that there is a platonic object associated with whatever arbitrary thing that we can think of.

But then, just after that, he says that this platonic object would be the ruliad, and in other writings, such as this (https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2022/03/the-physicalization-of-metamathematics-and-its-implications-for-the-foundations-of-mathematics/) he precisely says that all formal systems that we can think of would be platonic objects that would exist.

So this seems a bit contradictory to me: He first explains, apparently, that observers like us determine what axioms are true and what axioms are not and that there are no platonic objects associated with abstract things we can think of, but then he says that all axioms are equally valid and exist in the ruliad as some kind of platonic elements...

Perhaps I did not understand something and someone can clarify this a bit?

Comment: For Wolfram ruliad could be very concrete if not the most concrete, not abstract at all...

Comment: @DoubleKnot I don't understand your comment, as Wolfram has clearly said multiple times that the ruliad is an abstract thing that necessarily exists and contains all possible abstract formal systems (see: https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/11/the-concept-of-the-ruliad/, https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2022/03/the-physicalization-of-metamathematics-and-its-implications-for-the-foundations-of-mathematics/)

Comment: Formal systems/our "math" are not as abstract as the ruliad. As an analogy, human mathematics is like physicists working with stat mech instead of "raw" atoms. What makes stat mech true? The the most fundamental physics/the ruliad, which is beyond our limits forever. The "awkward" level of stat mech/human math is not false, but is not as abstract as deeper existence. Your attribution to W, "all axioms are equally valid and exist in the ruliad as some kind of platonic elements..," seems like a contradiction to his above language, but I can't find him saying that in your links.

Comment: Just like we can never track physics down the the most fundamental level, even in heat death, the ruliad/absolute abstraction, "goes on forever, in effect continually generating “irreducible surprises"”. Rather than contradiction then (which I can't support from your links), I'd offer if he did say that, he was speaking hastily. He seems to consistently say that "abstract" is forever beyond human capabilities, and our products can only be more and more abstract, never absolute. If you can find a quote for your contradiction that would support your claim, but I cant find a textual contradiction

Comment: Platonism is a kind of realism and he regards ruliad as real , like quantum wave function…

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because clarity on youtube videos should be directed to the author of that video. this is not a forum to clarify youtube videos

Comment: @JKusin Wolfram's theory proposes that everything we see in physics and mathematics is the product of us, as observers, sampling some part of the ruliad. In (https://www.wolframscience.com/metamathematics/) he says "We can think of the ruliad as the entangled limit of all possible computations—or in effect a representation of all possible formal processes".

Comment: @JKusin and then in (https://writings.stephenwolfram.com/2021/04/why-does-the-universe-exist-some-perspectives-from-our-physics-project/), you can search the phrase "all possible formal" in the writing and you can find things like "And what we can now say is that there is something because—essentially as a matter of definition—all possible formal rules inevitably in some abstract sense exist" or "We’ve argued that the existence of the universe is ultimately a consequence of the fact that all possible formal systems exist as a matter of abstract necessity"

Comment: I still don’t see him saying formal rules are abstract objects. Maybe there is a bit of sloppiness that crosses the line into contradiction, but if he actually were meaning formal systems are abstract objects he would say it. He seems to be struggling like Everettian quantum mechanics proponents want to say our reality is not the fundamental level, but the “entanglement” of all physical worlds is. I still do not think he means there is a 1 to 1 abstract collection of human stated formal rules/systems in the ruliad from all your links. That’s my textual interpretation, we don’t have to agree.

Comment: Ruliad is like necessarily complex-valued probability amplitude evolving in time domain according to Schrodinger's or Dirac's equations which you may firmly believe it's the only abstract real substrate reducing every macro phenomenon. In this sense all classical physics laws (axioms) are mere regression or Bayesian posterior updates like statistical mechanics thus there're no platonic objects associated with these classical systems. OTOH all different rules further describing either a free or trapped-in-infinite-potential-well quantum are equally valid Platonic objects with such a view.

Comment: @JKusin what do you mean with " I still do not think he means there is a 1 to 1 abstract collection of human stated formal rules/systems in the ruliad from all your links"?

Comment: @vengaq I mean, no formal system or mathematics humans have produced is at the fundamental level. Our formal systems and math are at the "awkward level" in his speak, and that awkward level exists because of the ruliad, but does not mirror it. When I said "are not in the ruliad" they are still part of existence, but not at the fundamental level - like statistical mechanics "exists", but its objects are not fundamental and don't mirror anything at the fundamental level of physics. They do not resemble/mirror/have a 1 to 1 relation to abstract objects and thus aren't abstract objects.

Comment: @JKusin that makes sense